# Is it necessary to install virtualization or VM ware to use Ubuntu on a PC laptop?

Tags: virtualization

This relates to learning RubyOnRails which I believe is often installed on or with Ubuntu.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu through 3 methods. 1: install it as a virtual machine through virtualization software (VMware, VirtualBox, etc.). 2: install it inside Windows (it will appear as a normal Windows program); when you boot your machine, you'll be greeted with the choice of operating system to boot to (this method is done using a program called Wubi). 3: install it on it's own partition (dualbooting). You'll also be greeted with the choice of OS to boot to.

Answer (score 0):

Necessary? Certainly not. You can *replace* your laptop's operating system with Ubuntu and that works well for a lot of people.

But if you're happy with your existing operating system and just want Ubuntu for testing a Rails stack, virtualisation offers a quick, easy and non-permanent method for getting going.

There are even [pre-built "virtual appliance" images](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/rails) for testing Ruby which might be the quickest way to get developing but I would strongly advise against pushing these to production.